# How to prove that $\lim\frac{\sum^{n}_{i = 1}{i^n}}{n^n} = e / (e - 1)$

Tags: calculus

It is easy to show that $\displaystyle\sum^{n}_{i=1}i^n/n^n < e/(e - 1)$, the question is to show the other direction.

Comment: You might try to bound (a) $e^{i-n} - i^n/n^n$ and (b) the effect of a finite sum

Comment: @geetha290krm I think it is supposed to be $\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty}$